# Heroku: No such file or directory after build

Tags: express, heroku, build

I am trying to deploy a new app to Heroku using the build process on Heroku (it picks up the code changes from github and builds automatically).  The client folders and package.json are in the root folder and the express files (including a separate package.json) are under /server.

{"error":"ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/build/index.html'"}

While troubleshooting this issue I launched bash and did a "dir" inside of the app directory.  Sure enough, no "build" folder in root.  I had overhauled a few things to separate the server's build from the main build - could I have screwed something up?  Am I wrong in my understanding of what happens on Heroku?

Here is the package.json in root:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server/index.js",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "dev": "SET NODE_ENV=development&& node server/index.js",
    "test": "SET NODE_ENV=test&& nodemon --exec mocha --recursive",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd server && npm install && npm run build"
```

**EDIT**
Not sure if something else is going on here.  I went into root on the server and issued "npm run-script build" and the build folder is now there and I can see index.html there.  However, same error persists.

Comment: Hey I don't know if you still need help on this but something to keep in mind is that files in heroku are case sensetive so it might not work if there is an upper-case letter

Answer (score 0):

Closing this as I had a more fundamental issue